# How to enable local storage for my firebase app

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My app send somme data to firebase storage but it is possible that the connection is off when the app want to send those data. I hear that i can achieve that by enabling local storage, i want to known how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the following site - https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/offline-capabilities.html

Comment: For the Firebase update that was released at last week's Google I/O, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/offline-capabilities (the content is very similar at the moment, but the firebase.com link will not be updated going forward).